# What are the typical behaviors of a Baby Leopard Gecko? It escaped its enclosure, not sure where to look anymore

Tags: behavior, leopard-geckos

My sibling breeds leopard geckos, we kept one as a pet, and it somehow disappeared from a 12in x 12in x 10in box with a roof on it (Temporary location while it grows)

We think it climbed on the log hide, and got through a tiny gap on the front of the cage, but we aren't sure.

The last time it was held was on Halloween, and was supposedly last fed in the past 2 days (Since the worms dropped in the feeding spot were gone, and nowhere to be found in the cage)

I'm not the one who takes care of the baby, but I worry for the poor thing, its tiny, and its in a house with 2 savage cats and a dog who will most likely eat / attack the baby if they see it come out of my sibling's room under the door or something.

I'm already considering the chance that he is gone, and perhaps no longer alive, but I'm hopeful, and I want to know if anyone knows the typical behaviors of where these lizards would hide? Like what kind of temperatures would they try to find in a room, where would they try to hide (Like in clothing, under furniture or towels / bedding or something??) that I most likely wouldn't think about? I'm sure this is really vague and unhelpful, but I don't know who else to ask

Tomorrow morning I'm going to dig around the room and see if I can find the poor thing before it starves, if it's even still in there..

Any other tips? Is there a way to "attract" the lizard or possibly coax him into coming out of hiding?

I've dug around my entire house, checked under and even inside of couches and furniture, but he is so small compared to our adults, so I fear that I wont find him if he is even still alive.. I don't know why in hell my sibling decided it would be best to store the lizard in a plastic drawer, but its a bit late to change it now..